# iPad OTA pushed update

Tags: ipad, software-update, jailbreak, ipados, auto-update

I have an iPad Pro (3rd generation 12.9) jailbroken with #unc0ver on 12.3.1
(I’ve had an issue saving blobs on this device.) I saw a pushed update for iPadOs to 14.3. Can I update to this since it's not signed anymore, or would it force me to 14.4? I also restated out of jailbroken state and the Pushed OTA is still 14.3. I just don’t want it to force me to 14.4 since 14.3 Is no longer signed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert on how iOS/iPadOS OTA works, but my understanding is that it depends on whether or not the update has been locally downloaded yet.

If you check Settings > General > Storage and see the iPadOS 14.3 update somewhere in that list (where in the list it is depends on how large it is relative to other files/apps on your iPad), it's been downloaded locally. You *should* be able to update to it, as the locally downloaded copy should be signed.

If you don't see the update file listed, it's likely a cache issue and pressing the button will likely cause it to refresh and download iPadOS 14.4. Some older updates (back when OTA was newer) acted as bridge updates to newer versions, but that's not been the case since well before iPadOS was forked from iOS.

Again, I can't say with any sincerity that this is all true and correct. What I *can* say with sincerity is that you shouldn't update at all if you're not 100% certain that you have saved blobs and are willing to potentially lose your jailbreak.

Comment: Owen, thanks for answering. So I did end up restarting out of jb state, the file is not currently downloaded. But it has downloaded before and I’ve gone into setting and deleted it. It dose show that 14.3 is what is being downloaded and it is not in jailbroken state when it shows that. I’ve had nothing but issues trying to create blobs on this device, but if I were to create blobs could I go back to 12.3.1 or would I be stuck on 14.4 if it won’t verify with Apple?

Comment: Sorry for not seeing this — if you create blobs, you should be able to downgrade back to 12.3.1. If the blobs can't be created, you would be stuck on 14.4 if you update.